# Export structure and data without a wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, export

Using Sql Server 2008 R2 (but I could possibly upgrade if required).

I want to generate scripts for the database structure as well as the data for a schema.

The Generate Scripts wizard does what I want but I need to be able to automate it (so needs to be called from T-SQL or alternatively external program).

How can I do this?

Comment: Data script can be generated by writing using TSQL like this http://www.connectsql.com/2010/12/sql-sqerver-generate-conditional-table.html

Comment: I think the best way is a PowerShell script, or other way to utilize SMO objects, like .Net app.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Red Gate SQL compare has a command line interface so you could write and schedule a batch file to generate the scripts. Details [here](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SC10/Using+the+command+line)

You could then use SQLcmd to execute the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to try PowerShell scripting for this.

- [Previous discussion here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56616/sql-server-2012-generate-scripts-from-command-line/56625#56625)
- [Example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/04/use-powershell-to-script-sql-database-objects.aspx)